# how can i merge two rows in same dataframe / pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

i have a dataset include these columns: 
(Order #,Waybill #,Order date,Scheduled for,Type,Delivery Fee,Cash collection,Worker,Dispatched,Completed,Assigned On,Status)

** each order represented in two rows first one type:PICKUP, second type:DELIVERY (with the same order# and some columns like:

```
   Unnamed: 0     Order #  Waybill #             Order date  \
0           0  9920000150        NaN  01 Aug, 2019 12:30 PM   
1           1  9920000150        NaN  01 Aug, 2019 12:30 PM   

           Scheduled for      Type  Delivery Fee  Cash collection   Worker  \
0  01 Aug, 2019 03:00 PM    PICKUP           NaN              NaN  Driver1   
1  01 Aug, 2019 03:00 PM  DELIVERY           NaN            135.0  Driver1   

              Dispatched              Completed            Assigned On  \
0  01 Aug, 2019 01:49 PM  01 Aug, 2019 01:51 PM  01 Aug, 2019 01:42 PM   
1  01 Aug, 2019 01:55 PM  01 Aug, 2019 02:08 PM  01 Aug, 2019 01:42 PM   

      Status  
0  Completed  
1  Completed
```

i want to merge two rows into one so the columns will be like this:
So the one column can represented like:
[Order #,Waybill #,Order date,Scheduled for,Delivery Fee,Cash collection,Worker,Dispatched_pickup,Completed_ pickup,Assigned On_ pickup,Status_ pickup,Dispatched_delivery,Completed_delivery,Assigned On_delivery,Status_delivery]

i just tried this and it doesn't work 
df1 = df.assign(cid = df.groupby(['Order #', 'Waybill #', 'Order date' , 'Scheduled for']).cumcount()).set_index(['Order #', 'cid']).unstack(-1).sort_index(1,1)

Comment: please show an example of your dataframe and your expected output

Comment: check the edit please

Comment: Don't include pictures of your data, copy and paste it to the question.

Comment: check the edit please

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick example, you can expand it to more columns. I renamed the columns so they don't have a conflict.

```
pickup_df = df[df['type'] == "PICKUP"]
delivery_df = df[df['type'] == "DELIVERY"]

pickup_df = pickup_df[['Order#','Waybill', 'Orderdate']]
delivery_df = pickup_df[['Order#','Waybill', 'Orderdate']]

pickup_df.rename( columns={'Waybill' : 'Pickup Waybill', 'Orderdate' : 'Pickup Orderdate'}, inplace=True)
deliver_df.rename( columns={'Waybill' : 'Delivery Waybill', 'Orderdate' : 'Delivery Orderdate'}, inplace=True)

combined_df = pickup_df.merge(deliver_df, on='Order#', how='left')
```

Comment: GREAT!! combined_df = pickup_df.merge(delivery_df, on=['Order #','Waybill #','Order date','Scheduled for','Delivery Fee','Cash collection','Worker'], how='left') its work

Comment: but the dates are copied! i mean  Pickup Orderdate+Delivery Orderdate in the new df not deferent like the original dataset